# Error analyzing c# project with Sonar 4.5.4

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-4.5

I got the following error when analyzing a c# project with SonarQube 4.5.4. I have the sonar-csharp-plugin-4.0 installed.

```
   Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor@18cf794...
    10:48:17.000 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-com.test.sample
    10:48:24.571 ERROR - 
    10:48:24.879 ERROR - Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    10:48:24.879 ERROR -    at SonarQube.CSharp.CodeAnalysis.Runner.Program.Main(String[] args)
    10:48:27.146 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-com.test.sample
    10:48:37.211 DEBUG - Updating semaphore batch-com.test.sample
    10:48:37.714 DEBUG - Release semaphore on project : org.sonar.api.resources.Project@494546[id=1442,key=com.test.sample,qualifier=TRK], with key batch-com.test.sample
```

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Here are two links that can help you: 
- http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/C-NEt-analysis-with-SDK-2-0-td5009614.html
- http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/FxCop-10-0-Error-with-Sonar-td5001854.html

Answer (score 0):

The C# plugin is implemented in C# itself (based on Roslyn) since version 4.0.

It requires the .NET framework 4.5 to be installed on the machine from which the analysis is being executed.